# Maximum number of sub-domains?

Tags: subdomain

If I own a domain (www.mydomain.com), what are the theoretical and practical limits on the number of sub-domains I can create (eg meta.mydomain.com, beta.mydomain.com)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's unlimited. For example, you can see

- wordpress.org: https://www.google.fr/search?q=site%3Awordpress.org
- or tumblr.com: https://www.google.fr/search?q=site%3Atumblr.com

When you create an account, you have your pseudo as a subdomain. And as you may know, Tumblr & Wordpress have a lot of members!

I found some interesting articles:

- [How many sub-domains can there be at most?](https://serverfault.com/questions/65920/how-many-sub-domains-can-there-be-at-most)
- [Maximum 'SEO Safe' Number of Sub Domains](http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/003948.html)